# Python: re.sub with os.path.abspath

Tags: python, os.path

I have a line in the file:
'some text /some/path'
where path can be both relative or absolute. I would like to replace it by an absolute path.
I tried this:

```
re.sub('some text (.*)','some text {}'.format(os.path.abspath(r'\1')),line)
```

However, the matched string is seen as a filename without any path and the resulting string is 
/path/to/the/file//some/path

Basically it is 'path/to/the/file/'+'matched_string' both for relative and absolute paths.
If I use os.path.abspath outside of re.sub it gives the correct path.

How can I fix this?

Thanks,
Ivan

Comment: You are calling `abspath()` on the literal string `\1`, which seems unlikely to accomplish anything useful.  You probably want to apply it to the result of `re.sub()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass a function as the replacement to `re.sub`, that function will be called with the match object as an argument:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, re

os.chdir('/tmp/')
line='some text .'

print(re.sub('some text (.*)',
             lambda match: 'some text {}'.format(os.path.abspath(match.group(1))),
             line))
```

...properly emits as output (on MacOS, where `/tmp` is a symlink to `/private/tmp`):

```
some text /private/tmp
```

Comment: @Ivan, glad to hear -- consider clicking the checkbox next to the answer to mark your question solved.